# Is it possible to stop the job in "starting" state?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

When I run a job with many steps, the job is still "starting" after 24 hours and does not start. I can't even cancel it because it is not running. I'm in trouble.[image]

Answer (score 1):

use

`gcloud dataflow jobs cancel <job-id>`

drain may not work because of several reasons. It depends on how the job and drain work. For drain to work, it should be able to successfully process the data if any. cancel would simply force kill the Dataflow job.

If that doesn't work, you may try some hard kills, like checking if any compute engine has been spun up, then kill that too. NOT Recommended but an option: Disable the Dataflow API temporarily (if no other job/user is using in your GCP project)

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about Dataflow job, you could try to stop (cancel/drain) it via Cloud Shell:

```
gcloud dataflow jobs {cancel|drain} JOB-ID
```

Comment: "gcloud dataflow jobs {cancel|drain} JOB-ID"  i tried it , but work....

Comment: Failed to drain job [2021-06-23_19_46_24-17194785053122778016]: (95fc877aa7ec79): Job 2021-06-23_19_46_24-17194785053122778016 is not a streaming workflow. Only streaming workflows can be drained. Please ensure you have permission to access the job and the `--region` flag, us-central1, matches the job's region.